# Move ROI rectangle by dragging the rectangle by mouse. Dragging works, but I need the coordinates from the dragged rectangle for moving the ROI

Tags: c#, wpf, image-processing, canvas, bitmap

I am still a rookie concerning C# and wpf. I added a “DragCanvas” so that I can drag every element inside that canvas. This works for example with a rectangle element I create statically inside the .xaml-file.

How can I reference to that rectangle, which was created inside the .xaml-file MainWindow.xaml.cs-file? I have to insert the width and height of the statically created rectangle, which was created inside the .xaml-file, inside my c#-code (inside my MainWindow.xaml.cs) and give it as arguments of the repositionROI function.

The topic of my project is to drag and position a rectangle which selects a ROI from a bitmap. At the moment, 5 rectangles are created as one clicks of the bitmap during runtime. The following code dynamically creates 5 rectangles, which selects 5 ROIs inside a bitmap:

```
private void drawROISelection()
        {
            this.manualROIselection = new Bitmap(this.originalScan);

            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(this.manualROIselection);

            Pen referencePen = new Pen(Color.DarkGreen, 10);
            g.DrawRectangle(referencePen, new Rectangle(referenceROI.x0, referenceROI.y0, referenceROI.width, referenceROI.height));

            Pen bluePen = new Pen(Color.Blue, 10);
            foreach (ROI roi in this.ROIs)
            {
                g.DrawRectangle(bluePen, new Rectangle(roi.x0, roi.y0, roi.width, roi.height));
            }

            bluePen.Dispose();
            g.Dispose();
        }
```

And then there is the code, which moves the rectangles respectively after new coordinates were typed in the MoveAllROI-Window.

That would be the following code:

```
private void MoveROI_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (ScanList == null) return;
            if (this.selectedIndex < 0) return;
            Scan selectedScan = scans[this.selectedIndex];
            int roiNumber = (int)ROITitleLabel.Tag;

            MoveROIWindow move = new MoveROIWindow(selectedScan.ROIs[roiNumber]);
            move.ShowDialog();

            if (move.DialogResult == true)
            {
                selectedScan.repositionROI(roiNumber, move.x0, move.y0, move.width, move.height); 
                PreviewStyle_Changed(null, null);
            }
        }
```

The moving of the ROI-rectangles must be done by dragging them in the new version of the program (dragging by mouse). There is a mouse-up event in the DragCanvas.cs-file. I need the coordinates of the dragged rectangle if the MouseButton is realead, i.e. end of the dragging of the rectangle. I guess I have to write a function, which gets the coordinates inside the following function inside the DragCanvas.cs-file?:

```
protected override void OnPreviewMouseUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreviewMouseUp(e);

        // Reset the field whether the left or right mouse button was 
        // released, in case a context menu was opened on the drag element.
        this.ElementBeingDragged = null;
    }
```

Or is it better to solve it with the “INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged Event”. With the latter I never done anything yet. So, I would have to read about it first. I am really stuck on this dragging ROI_rectangle problem and at first one thinks it could not be that difficult. I need a hint. Thanks in advance.

Edit: In my first post I also asked if I could reference my dynamically drawn rectangles inside the .xaml-file. That is of course not possible and does not make sense, because everything which is declared inside the .xaml-file are static elements and the dynamically drawn rectangles are only drawn during runtime of the program. Therefore this question only aims to find out how I reference to a rectangle which was statically created inside the .xaml file. My MainWindow.xaml.cs does not recognzize the rectangle name as a variable name inside the cs-code. I created the rectangle inside the .xaml file as follows:
`<Rectangle x:Name="ROI_rectangle1" Width="200" Height="25" Fill="Blue" Opacity="0.5" Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="3" Canvas.Left="135" Canvas.Top="213"/`>
and created it inside the DragCanvas because the rectangle has to be draggable during runtime.

Comment: There is still all those System.Drawing.Graphics stuff that shouldn't be in a WPF application. You can't "*reference to these dynamically drawn rectangles inside my .xaml-file*". Throw all that code away, and put a System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle on top of an Image element in a Canvas.

Comment: @Clemens: Yeah, I know that there is still System.Drawing as a using directive inside the C# project. That is because it is needed for reading the bitmap as a greyscale and take a crop outside that big bitmap as 5 different ROIs (region of interests). Ok, I cannot reference the dynamically drawn rectangles inside the .xaml-file. Understood. I edited my starting post regarding this. Makes sense that this is not possible because the .xaml-file is for static declarations of elements and the dynamic rectangles are only drawn during runtime of the program.

Comment: @Clemens: Ok, it shouldn’t be in a wpf project, but it still works if it is inside a wpf project. Shouldn’t does not mean it is not allowed inside a wpf project, right? I don’t know how to change the big C# project file, so that the reading of the bitmap works with System.Windows.Shapes or which using-directive I have to use instead if I use Windows.Shapes instead of System.Drawing and System.Drawing.Imaging. It would be too much work to change the existing C# project file too much.

Comment: @Clemens: If it is somehow possible that I can still use System.Drawing. in the project it would be much better, because it is too much work to change the existing code entirely. I was only supposed to implement the ROI-rectangle dragging function into the project in 3 days and it should not become a 3 week project.

Comment: IMO hat is a waste of time. Instead of trying to fix dead code, move to real WPF. At least when the code is supposed to be the basis for future development.

Comment: The software is just used in-house and is complete when the mouse-dragging feature of the 5 ROI(region of interest)-rectangles is implemented. Afterwards, the software is not touched again. Hmm, I’ll ask the original developer of it. I do not understand every function of it and a lot of functions use the windows.drawing directive.

Comment: @Clemens: ok, I only want to solve it with wpa. I created the following rectangle in the xaml-file: `<Rectangle x:Name="ROI_rectangle1" Width="200" Height="25" Fill="Blue" Opacity="0.5" Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="3" Canvas.Left="135" Canvas.Top="213"/> `. Do you know a hint how to reference to that rectangle?

Comment: `x:Name="ROI_rectangle1"` creates a field in the class that loads the XAML declaration. In code, just call `ROI_rectangle1.Width = 100;` or `Canvas.SetLeft(ROI_rectangle1, 100);`

Comment: @Clemens: hmm, but that does not work. I guess it still  has to do with the Windows.Drawing using directive, which is supposed for Winforms. I just created a new WPF-project and try to code the whole program fully in WPF. In the origin-code there is still too much Winforms stuff in it, I guess...

Comment: @Clemens: I can not change the project fully to a WPF project, because it uses the A.forge library and this only supports windows.drawing and not the WPF framework.